# Difference between antenna resistance and impedance

Tags: rf, antenna

From what I understand about antennas, they have a certain impedance.  At the antenna's resonant frequency, the capacitive and inductive reactances cancel and the reactive part of the antenna impedance is 0 ohms.  However, there is also something called the radiation resistance that still exists at resonance (for a dipole, it is commonly 71 ohms).  How can this be?  At resonance, doesn't the feedpoint of the antenna look like a short circuit due to resonance?  When the antenna is matched to a transmission line, do you use the reactance or the radiation resistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At resonance the imaginary part is zero, yes. Why is it surprising that there's still a real part?

Imagine a series (or parallel) RLC circuit. At the resonant frequency, the L and C impedance are equal and opposite. But you still have the R.

Another thing - the resistance that's left is not just radiation resistance, some of it is loss resistance - real resistive loss in the wires, etc.

Comment: So then why does the radiation resistance depend on the antenna type, and not just resistive losses in the coax/wire?

Comment: It's just the physics of the antenna. One explanation on a dipole is quite simple. A dipole has a fundamental characteristic mode, like a guitar string. If you wiggle a guitar string in the middle, where it moves a lot, then you will have to move a long distance, but not push very hard. If you hold it near the end, to get the same volume you'll only need to push a small distance, but with a lot more force. It's the same (but opposite) with a dipole. Feed it in the middle, 70 ohms. Feed it near the end, much higher impedance.

Comment: If the equivalent circuit of the antenna was purely C & L, then it would never (permanently) remove any energy from the circuit. Since energy is conserved, this would mean that it couldn't radiate any energy to be detected by a receiving antenna, and it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: It's worth remembering that if radiation resistance went to 0 at resonance, the antenna wouldn't make much of an antenna!